# Extent set to zero when you click the background

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, brush

I am using d3 to create a brush timeline much in the same way as [this](http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173) example.  If you hover over the top axis of the selection part of the chart, you notice that the cursor changes to a crosshair.  When you click it, the brush will disappear because it sets the extant to empty. Is there any way I can disable this?  I want to make sure the brush never simply disappears.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: you mean cursor to disappear i.e. crosshair.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying.  I'm talking about not wanting the brush to disappear when you click in the area that the cursor changes to a crosshair.

Comment: Which brush, there are 2 cursors - one the default one and another onclick crosshair.

Comment: I'm talking about the one that is on the top axis of the smaller graph on the bottom.  your curser turns into crosshairs when you hover over that top axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to edit `.on("brushend", funtion(){...})` to check for an empty brush and reset values if it is empty.  This insures that the user can never have an empty brush.  If anyone has questions about how to do this exactly, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Here are few options which get you same result, so try one that hides your crosshair when hover on top axis.

```
<rect class="background" x="0" width="885" style="visibility: hidden; cursor: none;"></rect>
```

(or)

```
$(".background").on('mouseenter',function(){
$(this).css('cursor','none');
});
```

(or)

```
    $(".background").on('click',function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

Comment: If I change the cursor and they click in that area, will the brush still disappear? My main issue is with the brush disappearing and not that there are crosshairs on hover.

Comment: @Ally I don't know about which brush you saying about. But it might be the green chart that disappears on click at top-axis, if so then try that updated (or) option code.